# Get Java exception class name in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, exception

I am using following code to call java web API

```
m$.ajaxq({
  url: contextPath + "/updateElapsedTime",
  type: "POST",
  data: params,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: 'text',
  async: optionalRunAsync,
  success: function (response) {
      console.log("Success")
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("Exception name is ...");
  }
});
```

Now there is a case when it throws custom exception.
I want to know which custom exception is thrown(classname) from java api and print it in javascript.

Comment: We can't help you without knowing exactly what your server sends back to the client when the exception occurs. Fundamentally, unless the server passes on the information about what exception class it was, your JavaScript code can't know. If it does, that's your answer: Use that information from the response.

Comment: As you said server exception is customized, then you can customize it to add class name in the exception message that you are sending back to client side and show it in the error block.

Comment: Use the browser debugger (or just console.log) against the 3 variables `jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown` to see if your exception class is in any of those.  If not, then you'll need to change the server to include it as that's all the information jquery/you have to work with.

Comment: Have you debugged what's in `jqXHR`, `textStatus` and `errorThrown` when it goes into the `error:`?

Answer (score 0):

Check if response is not 200. 
then use...

`xhr.responseText`

this will gives your custom error message